# How to load Javascript Library google chrome extention using chrome.runtime.getURL()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load this client side JavaScript library in my extension. I am getting a CORS issue, so I am taking googles recommendation and loading it from the disk.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

I'm trying to use the following code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", chrome.runtime.getURL('../lib/lit.js'), true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    // JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(resp);
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

This doesn't work, and returns an error

```
contains.js:12 GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

However, I can access the library just fine in my browser.

```
chrome-extension://npijdekijlclehcfenbajdainfncbfpi/../libs/library.js
```

Any ideas on why I can't load the file? (I plan on using eval after so I can use the library)

The permissions I have enabled is just "storage". I'm not sure if I need something else.

Comment: Have you tried NOT using `chrome.runtime.getURL` i.e. `xhr.open("GET", "../lib/lit.js", true);` ?

Comment: .getURL resolves from extension root path. You can't go to a root's parent.

Comment: This looks like a question which is an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). Please describe in more detail what it is you are attempting to achieve (not how you're attempting to achieve it).

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the file `'../lib/lit.js'` into the array `web_accessible_resources` in your manifest.json.

This way, you'll be able to use `chrome.extension.getURL` to get your file.

Read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).